# Why i cannot destructure 'input' and how can i get "title" which i pass in request?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

Declare typeDefs

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Todo {
        _id: ID,
        title : String, 
        done : Boolean
    }
    type QueryTodo {
        todos : [Todo]
    }
    
    input TodoInput {
        title : String
    }
    
    type Query {
        todos : [Todo]
    }
    
    type Mutation{
        createTodo(input: TodoInput): Todo
    }

`;
export {typeDefs}
```

Then in resolvers i declared key Mutation.
Code of my resolver below

```
import {Todo} from "../../DB/Models/Todo";


const resolvers = {
    Query:{
        todos:async()=>{
            return await Todo.find()
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        createTodo : ({input}) => {
            console.log(input)
            return {_id:"12312321",title:input,done:false}
        }
    }
}
export {resolvers}
```

When i try to make a request i get an error

```
mutation {
  createTodo(input: {
   title:"string"
  }) {
    _id
  }
}
```

response that i get is

"errors": [
{
"message": "Cannot destructure property 'input' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.",
"locations": [
{
"line": 2,
"column": 3
}
],
"path": [
"createTodo"
],
"extensions": {
"code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
"exception": {
"stacktrace": [

How can i get param "title" which i pass in request

Comment: What are you doing with `typeDefs` and `resolvers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers:

> A resolver function receives four arguments:
>
> - `obj` The previous object, which for a field on the root Query type is often not used.
> - `args` The arguments provided to the field in the GraphQL query.
> - `context` A value which is provided to every resolver and holds important contextual information like the currently logged in user, or
>   access to a database.
> - `info` A value which holds field-specific information relevant to the current query as well as the schema details

The first argument would be the `root` value of your schema for `Mutation` resolvers - apparently `undefined` if you didn't pass any. To access (and destructure) the arguments passed by your query, use the second parameter.